# Why Html to Wordpress converted site stops at preloader?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, preloader

i am converting an HTML template which has a preloader in its pages.
Now at basics, i converted index.html to home.php and separated header and footer and also finished up other settings.
Now the theme is shown perfectly in Wordpress and i activated it.
But when tested live the site, the site stops at preloader and infinitely preloader gif runs.
Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? Also notice that the `<div id="preloader"></div>` is in below header.php.
Here is the link of live site [visit site to see](http://jitendracomputerinstitute.epizy.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><!--This is header.php-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jitendra Computer Institute</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta content="" name="description">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Raleway:300,400,400i,500,500i,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/nivo-slider/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Nivo Slider Theme -->
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/css/nivo-slider-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Responsive Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- =======================================================
    Theme Name: eBusiness
    Theme URL: 
    Author: 
    License: 
  ======================================================= -->
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">

  <div id="preloader"></div>

  <header>
    <!-- header-area start -->
    <div id="sticker" class="header-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default cushycms">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                <!-- Brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll sticky-logo" href="index.html">
                  <h1><span>J</span>CI</h1>
                  <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
                  <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" title=""> -->
                </a>
              </div>
              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" id="navbar-example">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Courses</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Gallery</a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Downloads<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href=# >Our Prospectus</a></li>
                      <li><a href=# >Admission Form</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#blog">Students Portal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
            <!-- END: Navigation -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- header-area end -->
  </header>
```

Here is the index.php( I have included the  top part because it's very long)

```html
<?php
/**
/* Template Name: Home
 *
 * Displays Only Home template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Jitendra Computer Institute
 * @since Jitendra Computer Institute 1.0
 */
 get_header(); ?>
  <!-- header end -->

  <!-- Start Slider Area -->
  <div id="home" class="slider-area">
    <div class="bend niceties preview-2">
      <div id="ensign-nivoslider" class="slides cushycms">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-1" />
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-2" />
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/slider/slider3.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-3" />
      </div>

      <!-- direction 1 -->
      <div id="slider-direction-1" class="slider-direction slider-one">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="slider-content">
                <!-- layer 1 -->
                <div class="layer-1-1 hidden-xs wow slideInDown" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <h1 class="title1" style="color: white;">Jitendra Computer Institute</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- layer 2 -->
                <div class="layer-1-2 wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                  <h2 class="title2" style="color: white;">सिर्फ पढो नहीं कुछ सीखो भी</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- layer 3 -->
                <div class="layer-1-3 hidden-xs wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <a class="ready-btn right-btn page-scroll" href="#services">See Services</a>
                  <a class="ready-btn page-scroll" href="#about">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- direction 2 -->
      <div id="slider-direction-2" class="slider-direction slider-two">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="slider-content text-center">
                <!-- layer 1 -->
                <div class="layer-1-1 hidden-xs wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <h2 class="title1">Jitedra Computer Institute</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- layer 2 -->
                <!-- <div class="layer-1-2 wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                  <h1 class="title2">We're In The Business Of Get Quality Business Service</h1>
                </div> -->
                <!-- layer 3 -->
                <div class="layer-1-3 hidden-xs wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <a class="ready-btn right-btn page-scroll" href="#services">See Services</a>
                  <a class="ready-btn page-scroll" href="#about">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- direction 3 -->
      <div id="slider-direction-3" class="slider-direction slider-two">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="slider-content">
                <!-- layer 1 -->
                <div class="layer-1-1 hidden-xs wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <h2 class="title1">The Best Computer Institute</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- layer 2 -->
                <!-- <div class="layer-1-2 wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                  <h1 class="title2">Helping Business Security  & Peace of Mind for Your Family</h1>
                </div> -->
                <!-- layer 3 -->
                <div class="layer-1-3 hidden-xs wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                  <a class="ready-btn right-btn page-scroll" href="#services">See Services</a>
                  <a class="ready-btn page-scroll" href="#about">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Slider Area -->

  <!-- Start About area -->
  <div id="about" class="about-area area-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="section-headline text-center">
            <h2>About JCI</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the footer.php code

```html
  <!-- Start Footer bottom Area -->
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="footer-content">
              <div class="footer-head">
                <div class="footer-logo">
                  <h2><span>e</span>Business</h2>
                </div>

                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis.</p>
                <div class="footer-icons">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end single footer -->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="footer-content">
              <div class="footer-head">
                <h4>information</h4>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
                </p>
                <div class="footer-contacts">
                  <p><span>Tel:</span> +123 456 789</p>
                  <p><span>Email:</span> contact@example.com</p>
                  <p><span>Working Hours:</span> 9am-5pm</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end single footer -->
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="footer-content">
              <div class="footer-head">
                <h4>Instagram</h4>
                <div class="flicker-img">
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/5.jpg" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/img/portfolio/6.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-area-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="copyright text-center">
              <p>
                &copy; Copyright <strong>Jitendra Computer Institute</strong>. All Rights Reserved
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="credits">
              <!--
                All the links in the footer should remain intact.
                You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version.
                Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
                Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact form: https://bootstrapmade.com/buy/?theme=eBusiness
              -->
              This Site Is Developed and Managed By <a href="https://www.pathor.ml/">PathOr Groups</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>

  <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/parallax/parallax.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/nivo-slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript File -->
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/contactform/contactform.js"></script>

  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I guess the above files will be enough to analyze.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `footer.php` file if it's have code in it and the `wp_footer()` function inside. Your website missing the "footer" part (`</body></html>`, etc...) and don't have any Javascript files loaded, and some of Javascript file that will remove the preloader when page is loaded.

[image]

Comment: hey, first a big thanks for replying! And yes my HTML template has everything from CSS to js. In the home.php code, i haven't shown the whole code as it is very large. Please refresh the page I have included my footer.php code.

Comment: Now I see it loaded fine and able to remove the preloader. Because now it's loaded the required javascript files :)

Comment: is the site is loading fine? really? here in my browser, i couldn't see that working yet. How? did the home page loaded completely after preloader?

Comment: Yes. Updated the screenshot to answer. Try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: a very big thanks to you you just help me fix the issue though it was a very small issue as I forgot to include the footer.php reference in home.php and if you haven't told me then that would be really headache. thank you thank you very much